# Extract date and time of a tweet tweepy Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have found a python script for extracting tweets and store to csv file. I am not familiar with python yet. Except the tweets, I need also to extract the date and the time of each tweet. I have found how to extract other characteristics, such as "retweeted", "retweet_count", but I am still stuck in date and time. 
The script is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import csv

#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = "..........................."
consumer_secret = "..........................."
access_key = "..........................."
access_secret = "..........................."
screename = "@realDonaldTrump"


def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    #Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method

    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret )
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []  

    #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screename ,count=200)

    screen_name = "Donald J. Trump"
    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    #keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)

        #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screename,count=200,max_id=oldest)

        #save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

    #transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8"), tweet.favorite_count, tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorited, tweet.retweeted] for tweet in alltweets]

    #write the csv  
    with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name , 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text","favorite_count","retweet_count","favorited","retweeted"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)

    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    get_all_tweets(screename)
```

Comment: what is the JSON output of one tweet? Meaning, what are all the key:value pairs associated with a tweet.

Comment: I was rather rushed to ask the question.. Finally I found the solution, it was in front of my eyes. I added these lines:

Comment: print([method_name for method_name in dir(object)])
     print(tweet.__dict__.keys())

Comment: and I found, it was the tweet.created_at

Answer (score 0):

The tweepy tweet model has [created_at](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v2_models.html#tweepy.Tweet.created_at):

```
created_at
    Creation time of the Tweet.

Type
    datetime.datetime | None
```

Interesting fact is that you can derive the time from the tweet id. Tweet IDs are k-sorted within a second bound. We can extract the timestamp for a tweet ID by right shifting the tweet ID by 22 bits and adding the Twitter epoch time of 1288834974657.